# Looping thru 2 set of data in puppet - optimalization

Tags: apache, puppet

I need advice in optimizing my puppet code. As input I have 2 types of data - array that contains port numbers and hash that contains vhost details, and I like to mix each of them with another (every vhost for every port). Result should be apache::vhost for every vhost and port. Let's assume these class:

```
class proxy(
  $ports = ['80', '8080'],
  ) {
  class { 'apache':
    default_vhost => false,
  }

$vhosts = {
'myhost1' => {
  serveraliases => ['page.myhost1', ],
  proxy_pass    => [
    {
      'path' => '/url/',
      'url'  => 'http://localhost:8088/anotherurl/'
    },
  ],
},
'myhost2' => {
  serveraliases => ['page.myhost2', ],
  proxy_pass    => [
    {
      'path' => '/url/',
      'url'  => 'http://localhost:8088/anotherurl/'
    },
  ],
},
 proxy::vhosts { $ports:
  vhosts => $vhosts,
 }
}
```

Now I need to do a little magic to make vhost define uniq (I'm appending port number to vhost name in form myhost1_80):

```
define proxy::vhosts (
  $vhosts,
  ) {

  $vhosts_keys = keys($vhosts)

  $servername_port_string = join($vhosts_keys, "_${title},")
  $servername_port_string_full = "${servername_port_string}_${title}"

  $servername_port_array = split($servername_port_string_full, ',')

  proxy::vhost { $servername_port_array:
    vhosts    => $vhosts,
    port => $name,
  }

}
```

Finally creating apache::vhost for each vhost and port after splitting define name previously merged(so host1_80 splitting into host1 and 80):

```
define proxy::vhost (
  $vhosts,
  $port,
  ) {

  $servername_and_port = split($name, '_')

  apache::vhost { $name:
    servername    => $servername_and_port[0],
    serveraliases => $vhosts[$servername_and_port[0]]['serveraliases'],
    docroot       => '/var/www',
    port          => $servername_and_port[1],
    directories   => [
      { 'path'     => '/var/www',
        'provider' => 'files',
        'deny'     => 'from all'
      },
    ],
    proxy_pass    => $vhosts[$servername_and_port[0]]['proxy_pass'],
  }

}
```

Unfortunately apache class doesn't support array as input for port value, and I can't use newer versions of puppet > 3.2(as far as I remember - with each and other new features introduced). Can these be done in simpler way ?

Comment: Typical XY problem answer. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Well I can add entry to hash for each vhost and each port  but it will mean I need to create (no of vhosts * no of ports) entries in hash since I can provide only one port at a time to apache::vhost, wanted to automate this a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Puppet 3, you can use `create_resources`, combined with some ruby:

```
define b(
  $port,
  $vhost)
{
  notice("created ${vhost}:${port}")
}

class a(
  $all_ports,
  $all_vhosts,
) {
  $y = inline_template("<%= require 'yaml'; \
                        t = @all_ports.product(@all_vhosts).map { |(port, vhost)| \
                          [\"#{port}:#{vhost}\", { port: port, vhost: vhost }] \
                        }; \
                        YAML.dump(Hash[t]) %>")
  $spec = parseyaml($y)
  create_resources('b', $spec)
}

class { 'a':
  all_ports  => [8080, 80],
  all_vhosts => ['one.example.com', 'two.example.com'],
}
```

`parseyaml` is from stdlib. It would be prettier if you created a puppet function rather than using `inline_template`.

Comment: Thanks, looks much cleaner than my resolution, will definitely check that solution this week.